# How to separate text into different columns in Python?

Tags: python

How can I separate the following text into different columns?

**Input Text:**

```
[2010-07-01 -- 2013-12-18] Richard Yasenchak;[1999-01-04 -- 2006-02-28] Dennis J. Trittin;[1999-07-01 -- 2002-03-01] Brian C. Tipple;
```

**Output:**

```
| Start Date | End Date | Name |
| -------- | -------------- |----------|
| 2010-07-01   | 2013-12-18 |Richard Yasenchak |
| 1999-01-04   | 2006-02-28 | Dennis J. Trittin|
| 1999-07-01   | 2002-03-01 | Brian C. Tipple|
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.split(';')`?

Comment: We love that you're here with us and you need to show us your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Either use regex or multiple `split`ting and `strip`ping to get the desired output

Comment: You could use next regex: [`\[(?P<start_date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s*-+\s*(?P<end_date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\]\s*(?P<name>.*?)(?:;|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/LlWz0W/1).

Comment: what did you try? where is your code? You have it as string so you can all string functions to reformat it. For example you can use `split` with `;` to split into list of lines. And next you can use `split` with `]` to split line into string with dates and rest. And later you can use `split` with ` -- ` to split dates into separeted elements.

Comment: did you create this text? Next time use `\n` to seperate rows and `;` to separate elements in row and you will have normal CSV file - so you can use module `csv` or `pandas` to easly read/write/reformat

Comment: if you want output as text then you can use `replace` - `text = text.replace(";", " |\n")` `text = text.replace("] ", " | ")` `text = text.replace("[ ", " | ")`  `text = text.replace(" -- ", " | ")`

Answer (score 0):

Here my main idea is to convert string to list and than extract Name and date.

Code:

```
import string
t = "[2010-07-01 -- 2013-12-18] Richard Yasenchak;[1999-01-04 -- 2006-02-28] Dennis J. Trittin;[1999-07-01 -- 2002-03-01] Brian C. Tipple;"
t = t.replace("[", "")# here I am replacing '[' ']' so will not bother for date extraction
t = t.replace("]", "")#


l = re.split(r';', t) #here I am splitting data by ';' which is represting the a row data
l = [words for segments in l for words in segments.split()]
l

def is_date(date_string): #function to identify the date format
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y-%m-%d')
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

start_date = []
end_date = []

# as date are in sequence I am taking first as start and second as end 
#and trying to follow this sequence using below loop
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    if is_date(item):
        if len(start_date)==0:
            start_date.append(item)
        elif len(start_date)>len(end_date):
            end_date.append(item)
        else:
            start_date.append(item)

#after getting date from string
#trying to take out only word from string
names = ''.join([x for x in t if x in string.ascii_letters + '\'-'])
names = re.split(r'-', names)
names = [x for x in names if x]

#creating DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Start Date'] = start_date
df['End Date'] = end_date
df['Name'] = names

# giving space between first and last name by the capital latter
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace( r"([A-Z])", r" \1").str.strip()

df
```

Output:

```
    Start Date  End Date    Name
0   2010-07-01  2013-12-18  Richard Yasenchak
1   1999-01-04  2006-02-28  Dennis J Trittin
2   1999-07-01  2002-03-01  Brian C Tipple
```

If you wish you can short the code as well.

Comment: you should describe what you do.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it as text then simply use `replace`

```
text  = "[2010-07-01 -- 2013-12-18] Richard Yasenchak;[1999-01-04 -- 2006-02-28] Dennis J. Trittin;[1999-07-01 -- 2002-03-01] Brian C. Tipple;"

text = text.replace(";", " |\n")
text = text.replace("] ", " | ")
text = text.replace("[", "| ")
text = text.replace(" -- ", " | ")

text = '''| Start Date | End Date | Name |
| -------- | -------------- |----------|\n''' + text

print(text)
```

Result:

```
| Start Date | End Date | Name |
| -------- | -------------- |----------|
| 2010-07-01 | 2013-12-18 | Richard Yasenchak |
| 1999-01-04 | 2006-02-28 | Dennis J. Trittin |
| 1999-07-01 | 2002-03-01 | Brian C. Tipple |
```

---

And if you want it as `list` or `DataFrame` then you can use `split()` to split it in different places. i.e. `";"`, `" -- "`, `"] "`. First to split lines, next to split line into dates and name, and finally to split dates into date1, date2.

```
text  = "[2010-07-01 -- 2013-12-18] Richard Yasenchak;[1999-01-04 -- 2006-02-28] Dennis J. Trittin;[1999-07-01 -- 2002-03-01] Brian C. Tipple;"

all_lines = text.split(';')

all_rows = []

for line in all_lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:  # check if line is not empty
        dates, name = line.split('] ')
        date1, date2 = dates.split(' -- ')
        date1 = date1[1:] # remove '['
        
        all_rows.append([date1, date2, name])
        
for row in all_rows:        
    print(row)
```

Result:

```
['2010-07-01', '2013-12-18', 'Richard Yasenchak']
['1999-01-04', '2006-02-28', 'Dennis J. Trittin']
['1999-07-01', '2002-03-01', 'Brian C. Tipple']
```

And you can convert it to `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=['Start Date', 'End Date', 'Name'])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Start Date    End Date               Name
0  2010-07-01  2013-12-18  Richard Yasenchak
1  1999-01-04  2006-02-28  Dennis J. Trittin
2  1999-07-01  2002-03-01    Brian C. Tipple
```

Or you can format to expected output. And you can use `join()` for this.

```
text = '''| Start Date | End Date | Name |
| -------- | -------------- |----------|\n'''

for row in all_rows:
    text += "| " + " | ".join(row) + " |\n"
    
print(text)
```

Result:

```
| Start Date | End Date | Name |
| -------- | -------------- |----------|
| 2010-07-01 | 2013-12-18 | Richard Yasenchak |
| 1999-01-04 | 2006-02-28 | Dennis J. Trittin |
| 1999-07-01 | 2002-03-01 | Brian C. Tipple |
```